# Are these two commands to kill a process effectively similar?

Tags: systemd, init.d, kill, sysv

I'm looking at some `init.d` scripts, and a number of them use this what is essentially this command in their "`stop)`" target:

```
kill $(pidof ${DAEMON_NAME})
```

The `pidof ${DAEMON_NAME}` is actually a script function that checks the status code and calls exit if necessary, nonetheless, **How is the above any different than this:**

```
killall ${DAEMON_NAME}
```

A lot of `init.d` script simplification would be had if they are.

***EDIT:***
I should add these "processes" aren't daemons and don't actually record their PID in the FS anywhere ...

Comment: U&L is your friend: https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=kill+killall displays among other questions: [What is the difference between kill , pkill and killall](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/252349/what-is-the-difference-between-kill-pkill-and-killall). Hope that helps.

Comment: @Paul U&L? I read through the post ... it sort of confirms my suspicions.  Thanks.

Comment: I think killall is some sort of Kill-9 and not to send a SIGHUP

Comment: @eichertc No it isn't.  It sends SIGHUP to processes that match the name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, they are functional identic.

*pidof* is a shell function.

Note that *killall* came after *kill* and was not available in all Linux/Unix variants.

So the kill/pidof was the more generic appoach if you had to write init-scrips.